# iOS: Remove padding in UIPageControl

Tags: html, ios, swift

I have an app with compatibility from iOS 12 to 14 and have a problem with the page control.
On iOS 14 it has a huge padding which it doesn't have in older iOS version. Interface builder also shows this padding. My Problem is that I don't want this because my page control is not centred but left aligned in the UI.

[image]

How can I remove the padding so that it looks identically on all iOS versions?

Comment: Have the same question. Haven't found anything to help. Interested in an answer as well.

Answer (score 19):

This issue is because of **ios 14**.
I used below combination of code for ios 14 and it worked like a charm

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
  pageControl.backgroundStyle = .minimal
  pageControl.allowsContinuousInteraction = false
}
```

Comment: same answer as from bee8ee.

Comment: check the method body and compare it’s not same answer. Try to use my code and check it should work

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find was to create outlets for the page control constraints and change their constants to adjust the control's position for iOS 14. Here's my code: (My control is right aligned, so you should adjust for left alignment)

```
    // iOS 14 introduced extra padding to the UIPageControl. We adjust its constraints to keep it displayed in the lower right corner of the superview
    if #available(iOS 14, *)
    {
        pageControlTrailingConstraint.constant = -30
        pageControlBottomConstraint.constant = -3
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, but I wonder if this is really what Apple has designed